# Create android window with no background activity

Tags: android, dialog, popup

Im looking for a way to create android window which will contain a button, the window should be small, but i want it to contain no parent activity.
So, if the launcher is opened and the app is launched, the back will be the launcher, and still usable.. (so transparent activity is not good)..
I saw dialog and popupWindow are options, can it be done with any of them? Any other API?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) is a third-party library that lets you create floating windows and its fairly easy to create them. There are few examples on the GitHub page so you should check them out

Comment: Tried it, it keeps crushing... and i need some functionality they eliminate

Comment: The great thing is that it is open source so you can tweak it to better suit you needs